# how to add header parameter to url and get value from json url in android

Tags: android, json, authentication

I am new in android, I don't know how to add headers and value and get code.

I have a client id and client secret key. So i want to get gc code from the "http:.....grandcode.json", how to add headers and value .

**In Postman.successfully return code but could in android code.**
[image]

In above picture; I have client id and client secret key. and request url grant_code.json  and return on code. I want use this code but could not know to how to add headers value id and secret key.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to add that. Then show where you want to add it to to begin with.

Comment: Please read the docs for the class JSONObject http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, simple answer to add headers:

```
 StringBuilder builderVal= new StringBuilder();

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost request  = new HttpPost(urlGetGrandCode);
 request .setHeader("Header String","value");
 request .setHeader("Header String", "value");

 try {
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request );
    Log.e("RESOONSE", "response=="+response.toString());

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity =  response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builderVal.append(line);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        Log.e("search.class.toString()", "Failed to download file");
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

May be you output return on json as string.